# Transferring ownership of a question

Tags: support, feature-request

Often enough, by the time I get a reasonable answer to a question, I've already worked around it or upgraded software far past the problem (e.g. [I don't even own this camera anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139570/how-do-i-remove-all-metadata-from-a-quicktime-movie-file/).)  That puts me in the position of not being able to test out answers to give a checkmark.  Is there a way to contact question upvoters and transfer ownership to someone still interested in the problem?  If there isn't is there a way for me to recommend it as a feature?

Comment: Upvoting does not mean that they have that camera and interested in the solution

Comment: I agree personally contacting upvoters would be a messy spammy thing, I was hoping there might be some stackexchange mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

If you no longer have a vested interest in the question and it hasn't been reasonably answered (or you can no longer provide requested details). Just flag it to be closed at too localized. If someone comes along with a similar issue they'll be able to start their own question about it and follow up with it.

Comment: Really?  That question has what looks like good answers to a good question.  Does closing the question remove it from public view?

Comment: Like I said, "If you no longer have a vested interest in the question and it hasn't been reasonably answered (or you can no longer provide requested details)" It appears that question has been sufficiently answered. There's really no need to transfer ownership to someone else. If the answer doesn't work for someone new they can open a new question, citing your original question as their starting point, and the conversation can move forward from there.